# Network connectivity issue in the WSL2 when the host machine in on full tunnel VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have installed WSL2 on my corporate laptop (Windows 10 Enterprise version 1909). When my laptop is on a corporate VPN (Global Protect) with full tunneling, I lose network connectivity from the WSL2. I cannot do DNS lookup and also I cannot cURL to any website.

Everything works fine when my host laptop is off a VPN.

Note: WSL2 is using Hyper-V with Internal virtual switch.

Comment: Most likely the corporate VPN does not do or allow split tunneling. So when it is active, all network traffic goes through the tunnel. Your guest machine is likely on a different network (NAT).

Comment: Thanks, John. Is there a way change the NAT to the VPN Ethernet? Surprisingly, when I use DockerDesktop which also creates a VM and networking under the hood, the network connectivity works well from that VM while on the VPN.

Comment: That is probably up to your Company Administration.  It depends on how they set up the tunnel.

Comment: there are many people, including me, facing similar issue. check this https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5068 I'm afraid there is no solution.

Comment: If this is something that brings value to your Company, ask if they will install VMware Workstation on it or enable Hyper-V on and allow you to install Linux as a guest machine . VMware has excellent networking facilities and that will likely help you here.

Comment: got the similar issue with any connect VPN, maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/a/1666368/1469294